Redis MaxRetriesPerRequestError on Deployment to Render
I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js server when I deploy it to Render. The server works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it, I receive the following error related to Redis:
missing 'error' handler on this Redis client
/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/event_handler.js:182
self.flushQueue(new errors_1.MaxRetriesPerRequestError(maxRetriesPerRequest));
                                    ^
MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.

Here are the details of my setup:

Node.js version: 20.12.2

Redis library: ioredis

Deployment platform: Render


What I have tried so far:

I set the maxRetriesPerRequest option to 20 in my Redis client configuration to control the retry limit.

I added error handling in my code to catch Redis errors.

The Redis connection seems to work on my local machine but fails when deployed to Render.


Here's my Redis connection code:
const { createClient } = require("redis");

let redisClient = null;

async function connectRedis() {
  if (redisClient && redisClient.isOpen) {
    return redisClient;
  }

  redisClient = createClient({
    password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
    socket: {
      host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
      port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
      reconnectStrategy: (retries) => {
        console.log(`Attempt ${retries + 1}: Reconnecting to Redis...`);
        return Math.min(retries * 100, 3000); // Retry after 100ms up to 3000ms
      },
    },
    maxRetriesPerRequest: 20,
  });

  // Error handling
  redisClient.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Redis error:", err);
  });

  redisClient.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connected to Redis successfully.");
  });

  redisClient.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Redis client is ready.");
  });

  redisClient.on("reconnecting", () => {
    console.log("Redis client is reconnecting...");
  });

  redisClient.on("end", () => {
    console.log("Redis connection closed.");
  });

  try {
    await redisClient.connect();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to Redis:", error);
  }

  return redisClient;
}

module.exports = connectRedis;

Logs from last version:
/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/event_handler.js:182 
self.flushQueue(new errors_1.MaxRetriesPerRequestError(maxRetriesPerRequest) 
                 ^
MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). 
Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details. 
at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/event_handler.js:182:37) 
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26) 
at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28) 
at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12)


What could be causing the MaxRetriesPerRequestError error specifically when deployed to Render but not locally?

Are there any additional configurations or steps required when using Redis with Render that I might be missing?


Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

please share the log you get from the version your showing. share redis deployment and running details, share redis logs.

/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/event_handler.js:182 self.flushQueue(new errors_1.MaxRetriesPerRequestError(maxRetriesPerRequest)                                   ^
MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.
at Socket. (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/event_handler.js:182:37)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
at TCP. (node:net:337:12)

I think your issue is connectivity with redis, but i need redis deployment logs, and redis logs to check that
